# LWC get element by value

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, js, queryselector

Why can't I get element by value? I have tried to get id with var, just data and different quotes.

```html
//var = id;
<lightning-input value={var}></lightning-input>
```

```js
this.template.querySelector("lightning-input[value='id']");
// but just lightning-input works and value is correct
console.log(this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value);
```

Comment: if you will inspect the dom in dev console you will see that `lightning-input` does not have any attribute called `value`. only `data-`something are displayed in the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```html
//var = id;
<lightning-input data-value={var}></lightning-input>
```

```js
let id = '12345';
this.template.querySelector(`[data-value="${id}"]`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `lightning-input` with a `data-` (`data-"something-you-want-attribute"`) attribute in your **querySelector**.

So it will look in next way :
**HTML** :

```html
//value = id;
<lightning-input data-id={value}></lightning-input>
```

**JS** :

```js
value = 'some-id';

helperMethod(){
    let inputValue = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-input[data-id="${this.value}"]`).value;
}
```

Also I would not use **var** as parameter name in LWC (as it can be confused with the `var` keyword